# Select folder to store the file history in

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I looked at my file history settings today and it showed that it was disabled for some weird reason (I remember setting it up earlier).

When setting it up again, I was only able to select a drive. Previously I know I have been able to select a folder to use as the file history store (I have the folder to prove it), but I couldn't find this feature anywhere in windows 10 (both in the new and in the legacy config windows).

Is the option to store the file history in a specific folder still available or was it removed? And if it is still possible, can someone provide the steps to enable this again?

Comment: "Is the option to store the file history in a specific folder still available or was it removed?" - Are you asking if File History is still a feature? It is indeed still a feature.  If it was disabled then, a user action, disabled it.

Comment: @Ramhound no I am asking whether or not they removed the possibility to put the file history store in a sub folder in stead of in the root folder of a drive

Answer (score 3):

I see two possibilities :

**Assign the folder a drive letter**

Use the Windows `Subst` Command, available since Windows NT in the early
1990’s, and still present in Windows 10.

Usage is, in a Command Prompt (cmd) :

```
Subst [Drive:] [Pathtofolder]
```

To remove the mapping, enter the drive letter and add the /D argument:

```
SUBST X: /D
```

**Forcing Subst to Run on Startup**

If you want to run the command automatically every boot :

1. Open Regedit and navigate to the following
   For all users:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
   ```

For only the currently logged on user :

```
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

2. Right click on *Run > New > String Value* and give it some name
   such as `Map X`
3. Double-click on it and enter as value :

   ```
   Subst [Drive:] [Pathtofolder]
   ```
4. Close Regedit and reboot or re-logon

For more info see the article
[Map a Folder to a Drive Letter for Quick and Easy Access](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/map-folder-or-directory-to-drive-letter-for-quick-and-easy-access/)
for sharing the folders, and use the syntax of
`\\my-computer-name\share-name`.

**Make the folder a network share**

The Select Drive option lets you also specify network shares.

[image]

See the article
[Map Network Drive in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/54708-map-network-drive-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Thanks, these will at least make it possible to do what I wanted. The question though was more focused on that it was possible before and whether or not they removed the feature in windows itself. It is weird that one time I have a file history store in a folder, but now only am able to select a drive. I still upvoted the question, but I want to get to the bottom of the issue before marking anything.as answer.

Comment: Some changes done by Microsoft are just for simplifying buggy code, and losing options is the result. The community then needs to find workarounds or create third-party utilities to remake what was deleted.