# When using Windows 10 Backup, is it possible to persist defined folders after changing drives?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive

**Aim**

I'd like to have a simple system in Windows 10 where I backup known folders daily to an external drive for two weeks, then switch that out with a second external drive, and repeat this process every again every two weeks.

This mostly works.

**Problem**

When connecting the drive at the start of a two week process, by using the `Backup>More options>See advanced settings>Select drive` option I can select the existing backup.

[image: existing backup instances]

This allows me to easily see (and restore) old files through the convenient `Backup>More options>See advanced settings>Restore files from a current backup` option.

The problem is that once this drive is selected, it depopulates the Backup/Excluded folders, so I have to spend a chunk of time selecting the relevant folders.

**Question**

Can I conveniently use two drives with Windows backup, not having to redefine folders when I switch out backup drives every two weeks?

Comment: Do you refer to the deprecated Backup and Restore (Windows 7)?

Comment: I am referring to the the main Windows 10 Backup.

Comment: Not an answer: File History is not a good backup product and is not recommended. I say this because I have encountered so many issues here without real solutions like [post1](https://superuser.com/questions/1464052/windows-10-file-history-is-silently-refusing-to-back-up-some-of-my-files), [post2](https://superuser.com/questions/1383347/windows-file-history-include-exclude-order-of-precedence) and [post3](https://superuser.com/questions/1309129/select-folder-to-store-the-file-history-in). This is just for information.

Comment: If the question is about switching between two File History configurations, you may look into saving and restoring the `Config*.xml` files in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration`. You should first stop the system service File History Service (fhsvc). You might also have a look in registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\fhsvc\Parameters\Configs`.

Comment: It seems like those configuration files also exist at `[backup location]\Configuration`. I wonder what the relationship between the two places is and how I should modify them accordingly. I tend to agree with you, though. Even if jumping through these undocumented hoops works, it's presumably not supported by Microsoft and this method could fall apart if Microsoft changes how they handle configuration. It seems like Linux has a good number of backup options  which are full of features, stable and open source, so when WSL2 I'm thinking about using BUP.

Comment: Linux on Windows is sort of a moving target, while Windows has excellent free backup products. According to your needs, see [Best Free File-Based Backup Program](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-hard-drive-backup-program.htm) or see [Best Free Drive Cloning Software](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-cloning-software.htm) for reviews and user comments.

Comment: @Geesh_SO I've successfully modified the config xml's multiple times without issue... simply ensure you keep a copy of the main config (I keep mine in a nested folder within Documents).

Comment: @harrymc The three posts you reference are down to user error, with a possible isolated bug for #2, however to state overarchingly that File History is not a good backup product with no supporting effectual information is fundamentally flawed.  For example, no one bothered checking Event Viewer for the File History log... simply guessing blindly is a recipe for frustration.

Comment: @JW0914: File History was never meant to be a replacement for file backups or disk backup images. Treating is as backup software is just wrong, and posters should be warned against this. But please let's not continue with this, as this is not what the post is mainly about.

Comment: @harrymc I don't disagree that it's not a replacement for WIM backups, which are far more efficient _(especially with regards to backup file size)_, however your comment didn't differentiate that, which was my only point.  File History is a directory backup solution _(WIMs are still more efficient for directory backups)_ but by no means a replacement for backups using `DISM` to create WIMs: `DISM /<Capture-Image>OR<Append-Image> /Image:Z:\Backup.wim /CaptureDir:D:\ /Name:"Backup 1" /Description:"Partition D backup - 2019.08.19" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify`

Comment: @Geesh_SO Have you considered WIM backups every 2 weeks?  See my previous comment for an example command to capture an initial WIM, or append to a previously captured WIM.  WIMs are smart compression backups that support an unlimited number of backups in one image.  Each appended backup only copies into the image those files which have changed, which is managed by hashing, and provided the `/CheckIntegrity` and `/Verify` paramaters are always specified, it's impossible for a WIM to become corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the question is about switching between two File History
configurations.

I suggest as solution the saving and restoring of the `Config*.xml` files
in the folder `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration`,
which is the main configuration repository of File History.

While switching these files, you should first stop the system service
"File History Service (fhsvc)" and restart it afterward.
It is possible to automate the switching process by using two `.bat` files,
described below.

There are also other secondary places where File History keeps configuration
data, although I don't think they should also be switched.
These are the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\fhsvc\Parameters\Configs`
and `[backup location]\Configuration`.

User JW0914 in the above comments testifies that he uses this technique for
configuring File History.

Let's say that you have saved one configuration with the command:

```
copy "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration\Config*.xml" "C:\path\to\save1"
```

And that you repeated this for the second configuration that you wish
to save. So in the end you have two folders, `save1` and `save2`, for the two.

To return `save1` while stopping the File History service, you would
write a `.bat` file such as:

```
sc stop fhsvc
timeout 5 >nul
copy /y "C:\path\to\save1\Config*.xml" "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration"
sc start fhsvc
```

This batch file needs to run in Administrator mode.
You may store it on the desktop, or add a desktop icon that will point to it.
You should create two such, for `save1` and `save2`.

Explanation of the script commands:

- [The sc command](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) is used for controlling
  system services. It will here stop the service `fhsvc` for the duration of
  the operation, then will restart it.
- The [timeout command](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) will delay
  execution for five seconds, time enough for the service to terminate
  (increase if required), and its output is directed to the NUL device
  to avoid verbose output.
- The [copy command](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) is called with
  the `/y` parameter to suppress the confirmation prompt when overwriting
  the files.

Comment: Your offer to supply bat scripts would be welcome!

Comment: Script added above.